# QuerySet object has no attribute

Tags: python, django

I got a problem when I select the distinct value from DB.

Here is my model:

```
class Shift(models.Model):
    shiftid = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    shiftdesc = models.CharField(blank = False, null= False, max_length=20)
    dayname = models.CharField(blank = False, null= False, max_length=20)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('shiftid','dayname')
```

This is the resulting data structure:

```
shiftid shiftdesc dayname

shift1   desc1     1
shift1   desc2     1
shift1   desc1     1
```

I want it to be like this:

```
shiftid shiftdesc dayname

shift1   desc1     1
shift1   desc2     1
```

I am trying to select the records like this:

```
@action(methods=['get'], detail=False)
    def shiftsum(self, request):
        newest = self.get_queryset().order_by('shiftid','dayname').values('shiftid','dayname').distinct()
        serializer = self.get_serializer_class()(newest)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

When I try like that I always get this error:

> QuerySet object has no attribute 'shiftid'

Also, I would like to know how to select the distinct value? I am new in Django and appreciate every help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serializers don't handle lists of objects by default. You need to pass `many=True` to tell it to process each item and output a list ([rest framework docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-multiple-objects)).

```
self.get_serializer_class()(newest, many=True)
```

This will give you a list of days, like you expect:

```
[
    { "shiftid": "shift1", "dayname": "1" }
]
```

#### Distinct

Your distinct is fine. An example distinct query would look just like yours:

```
User.objects.values('field').order_by('field').distinct()
```

#### Final Query

The issue with your final query is that you are only selecting 2 of the 3 fields that you want, excluding `shiftdesc`.

There isn't really a logical way to get that value, since by definition you start with N and end up with 1.

If you just want *ANY* value for it, say for debugging or display, you can use `.annotate()` like this:

```
query = (
    Shift.objects.values('shiftid', 'dayname')
         .annotate(shiftdesc=Max('shiftdesc'))
         .annotate(ct=Count('*'))  # get count of rows in group
         .order_by('shiftid', 'dayname')
         .distinct()
)
```

Look into [annotations/aggregations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/), more advanced stuff can be done that may help out, and some database specific stuff that can be really useful.

#### Full Example

Here is a full example, using the default django User table.  You have not provided enough information to further debug it.

```
import json
from rest_framework.serializers import *

User.objects.create(email='x1@e', first_name='Angela', last_name='Smith')
User.objects.create(email='x2@e', first_name='James', last_name='Smith')
User.objects.create(email='x3@e', first_name='James', last_name='Joyce')

query = User.objects.values('last_name') \
        .order_by('last_name') \
        .annotate(first_name=Max('first_name')) \
        .annotate(ct=Count('email')).distinct()

class X(Serializer):
    last_name = CharField()
    first_name = CharField()
    ct = IntegerField()

data = X(query, many=True).data

print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
[
    {
        "last_name": "Joyce",
        "first_name": "James",
        "ct": 1
    },
    {
        "last_name": "Smith",
        "first_name": "James",
        "ct": 2
    }
]
```

Comment: I change like u said but still got the error.I have no idea why.

Comment: I can run that code directly, in the console, and easily.  You are going to have to tell me more than "I have an error".  My psychic debugging skills are a bit rusty.

Comment: if i return like "return Response(query)" i got the result but if i serialize and response like "serializer = self.get_serializer_class()(query)  return Response(serializer.data)"  it happen error.

Comment: Ohh please one more question, If i have total 5 field but i only want this 3 field,how to select this 3 field only? Am i need to create new serializer?

Comment: @Jze This answer already addresses the original question.  Please try to limit questions to 1 per post, and create a new question once you have resolved this issue.

Comment: Please help me to check my new question => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57179287/how-to-select-specify-field-only-in-viewset-django