# How to select specify field only in Viewset Django

Tags: python, django, django-serializer

I would like to select the distinct field and some field only from Django ViewSet.

My method

```
@action(methods=['get'], detail=False)
    def shiftsum(self, request):        
        query = (
                    Shift.objects.values('shiftid', 'dayname')
                        .annotate(shiftdesc=Max('shiftdesc'))
                        .annotate(ct=Count('*'))  # get count of rows in group
                        .order_by('shiftid', 'dayname')
                        .distinct()
                )
        serializer = self.get_serializer_class()(query,many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

My Model

```
class Shift(models.Model):
    shiftid = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    shiftdesc = models.CharField(blank = False, null= False, max_length=20)
    dayname = models.CharField(blank = False, null= False, max_length=20)
    dayno = models.IntegerField(blank = False, null= False)
    offin_f = models.IntegerField(blank = False, null= False)
    .
    .
    .
```

My serializer

```
class ShiftSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:        
        model=Shift
        fields = "__all__"

    def create(self,validated_data):      
        validated_data['Created_Usr']="Admin"             
        validated_data['Created_DT']=datetime.datetime.now()      
        validated_data['LastModified_Usr']=''            
        validated_data['LastModified_DT']=None            
        return Shift.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def update(self,instance,validated_data):       
        instance.shiftdesc = validated_data.get('shiftdesc',instance.shiftdesc) 
        instance.dayname = validated_data.get('dayname',instance.dayname) 
        instance.dayno = validated_data.get('dayno',instance.dayno) 
        instance.offin_f = validated_data.get('offin_f',instance.offin_f) 
        instance.offout_f = validated_data.get('offout_f',instance.offout_f)
```

When I select like that, Error message show

> "Got KeyError when attempting to get a value for field `dayno` on
>   serializer `ShiftSerializer`.\nThe serializer field might be named
>   incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `dict`
>   instance.\nOriginal exception text was: 'dayno'."

I would like to select the `shiftid` , `shiftdesc` and `dayname` only, How to select these three field only and am I need to create new serializer?

Comment: Can you show the full traceback?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem , Please check the update. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ShiftSerializer` uses `__all__`, which means it is going to try to serialize all the fields in your model.

Since the queryset you have specified doesn't include all your fields (and it is a sum/distinct, so it should not), then this is guaranteed to fail.

There are 2 options

1) Create a new serializer for only the fields you want, manually specifying them

```
class ShiftSum(Serializer):  # NOT model serializer
    shiftid = CharField()
    ... add other fields

return Response(ShiftSum(query, many=True).data)
```

2) Convert the queryset to a list, and just return it directly

```
data = list(query) # turns your queryset into [{"shiftid":"n", ...}, ]
return Response(data=data)
```

This last way works if the data coming out of your query is already the format you want, and already the correct type for simple JSON serialization (no datetimes, no `Decimal`, etc).  Try it and see if it works.

Comment: Thank you, You save my day again.

Comment: Happy I could help :)